# How can I use JSR-303 Bean Validation on a JAX-WS WebMethod?

Tags: jax-ws, bean-validation

I want to use bean validation within my web services. The best approach would be similar to a Spring MVC binding like this:

```
@WebMethod void sayHello(@Valid HelloDTO hello) {...}
```

The goal is to get rid of all the validate methods in the web service implementation. I would like to handle the validation as a cross cutting concern.

As I know Hibernate Validator >4.2 as well as Apache BeanValidation should be able to validate method parameters. But I have no idea, how to hook into the JAX-WS method parameters binding.

I tried to write a handler, that intercepts the message, but I had difficulites to unmarshal the payload in a general manner, because I was not able to determine what the parameters were. Additionally, a handler would be a very strict validation. I would like to let the developer of the web service decide, if he wants the input parameters to be validated or not.

**Edit**:
In the meantime I found a solution using Spring AOP to intercept calls to the endpoint. However, a solution using Handlers would be better, because the cross cutting concern of validating would be defined on a better, predefined, place: the handler chain.

This is the Spring solution:

Create an aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class ValidationAspect {
    @Autowired private Validator validator;

    // Alternative: use @annotation(javax.validation.Valid) to validate only methods annotated with @Valid
    @Pointcut("execution(* (@javax.jws.WebService *).*(..))")
    public void webServiceWebMethods() {}

    @Before("webServiceWebMethods()")
    public void validateWebService(JoinPoint jp) throws WebParamValidationFault {
        for (Object arg : jp.getArgs()) {
            Collection<ConstraintViolation<Object>> errors = validator.validate(arg);
            // check validation and throw exception if errors occured
        }
    }
```

Configure Spring-AOP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
    <bean id="validationAspect" class="ValidationAspect" />
</beans>
```

The `proxy-target-class="true"` will enable cglib proxying. This is necessary, because the JAX-WS runtime is not able to use the JDK dynamic proxy of the web service. The reason is, that `@WebService` is not inheritable and the proxy claims about the missing annotation. The solution is to use cglib **and** declare the implementation class of the web service Spring binding:

```
<wss:binding url="/demo">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#DemoEndpoint" impl="com.example.DemoEndpoint" />
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
```

Any solutions without using aspects are appreciated.

Comment: I think the main problem with any handler based solution is that from within a handler the unmarshalled objects are not accessible, only representations like `Source` etc. So you would have to unmarshal the request yourself and pass the unmarshalled objects to the validation engine. I think an Advice/MethodInterceptor based solution is as good as it gets.

Comment: @Gunnar You are probably right. Although it is possible to get the XML representation of the object within the handler, I was not able to unmarshall it in a general way. For example, the ObjectFactory is missing and I would like to have a general approach. However, I am quite satisfied with the Spring AOP solution.